# R Merging 4 Strings into 1 String

Tags: regex, r

I'm searching for the locations of 4 different substrings in x and trying to merge these four outputs into one cumulative string:

```
x <- ("AAABBADSJALKACCWIEUADD")
outputA <- gregexpr(pattern = "AAA", x)
outputB <- gregexpr(pattern = "ABB", x)
outputC <- gregexpr(pattern = "ACC", x)
outputD <- gregexpr(pattern = "ADD", x)
```

I would like to merge these four outputs and output this merged result as a text file with each element separated on new line.

```
merged_output
# 1
# 3
# 13
# 20
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can do it all at once using a lookahead `(?=)`

```
gregexpr("A(?=AA|BB|CC|DD)", x, perl=T)[[1]]
# [1]  1  3 13 20
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 1 1 1 1
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

For example

```
library(stringi)
cat("merged_output", 
    paste("#", 
          stri_locate_first_fixed(pattern = c("AAA", "ABB", "ACC", "ADD"), ("AAABBADSJALKACCWIEUADD"))[, "start"]), 
    file = tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt"), 
    sep = "\n")
```

Now, the file named in `tf` contains

```
> merged_output
> # 1
> # 3
> # 13
> # 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very automated, but

```
cat(paste(c(outputA[[1]][1], outputB[[1]][1], outputC[[1]][1], outputD[[1]][1]), 
          collapse = "\n"), 
    file = "outputfile.txt")
```

should do it.